# Http Only cookies vs Session

Tags: session, cookies, oauth

So I'm implementing integration with API that uses OAuth 2, which state: Recommend to use httpOnly Cookies to store the tokens (access, refresh).

I've used sessions for long time and I was not sure if there is any difference between using httponly cookie or session
Any pros vs cons?

HttpOnly cookies serve same security as session cookies
Except the extra work involved with session cookies (storing and clearing data)
Oauth 2 recommends the usage of HttpOnly cookies, but I wasn't sure why!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] (and earn a badge while you are at it) / Also read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community.  Your question, as stated right now, does not meet the community guidelines

Comment: @blurfus I've read and check similar questions, no one answered this question, I modified it a bit to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

Cookies and Sessions are used to store information. Cookies are only stored on the client-side machine, while sessions get stored on the client as well as a server. A session creates a file in a temporary directory on the server where registered session variables and their values are stored.

So...
The main difference between a session and a cookie is that session data is stored on the server, whereas cookies store data in the visitor's browser. Sessions are more secure than cookies as it is stored in server. Cookie can be turned off from browser.

Comment: Thanks, however I don't see the security improvement?!

Comment: Also why would oauth2 recommend it

Comment: Using the HttpOnly flag when generating a cookie helps mitigate the risk of a client-side script accessing the protected cookie (if the browser supports it). If the HttpOnly flag (optional) is included in the HTTP response header, the cookie cannot be accessed through a client-side script (again if the browser supports this flag). As a result, even if an XSS flaw exists and a user accidentally accesses a link that exploits this flaw, the browser will not reveal the cookie to a third party.

Comment: Read: The Fast Track to Safe and Secure PHP Sessions.

There are a few ways you can store session data:

Comment: In a file (PHP's default behavior)
In a database (many frameworks do this)
In memcached (what I do)
In the cookie itself (generally a bad idea)
Unless you're transmitting session data (i.e. your database is on another server, or your memcached is running on multiple servers and you're not sure that it's using TLS to communicate between nodes), you generally don't need to do anything to the session data.

Auto-login is actually a complicated subject and a separate concern from normal sessions. I've previously written about secure "remember me" cookies.