# Using HTTP only cookies in REST API, determining cookie "owner"

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, authentication, cookies

I'm building a REST api in Wordpress and want to use secure cookies for authentication.

My question is how the server determines the owner of the cookie, and which data needs to be passed from the client to be able to retrieve the cookies for that client?

I can set the cookies on the server, but on the next call, the cookies for the client is not accessible. I'm assuming some type of headers needs to be passed for the server to recognize that it's the same user that set the cookie.

I don't really have some code to show, since the question is more generally what is required for the server to recognize the client and access the secure cookies, but basically what I'm trying to is:

Javascript:

```
function setCookie() {
    const res = await fetch('/login', {username, password});
    
    console.log(await res.json()); // Success
}

function checkCookie() {
    const res = await fetch('/check-cookie');
    
    console.log(await res.json()); // False
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php

// Hooked to /login endpoint
function login($request) {
    // Check credentials, then set cookie:
    $cookie = setCookie('cookie-name', 'some-value', 0, '/', '', true, true);

    return $cookie ? 'Success' : 'Failed';
}

// Hooked to /check-cookie endpoint
function checkCookie() {
    return isset($_COOKIE['cookie-name']);
}
```

So first login in is successful on my attempts, but checking authentication on any additional request is unsuccessful.

Comment: FWIW Cookies aren't usually a great solution for an API, because they're only really intended for use by a browser, and of course an API generally is intended to be accessible by all kinds of HTTP clients (which _could_ use cookies, but it's usually not very convenient). Most APIs which require authentication use some kind of token-based authentication, based on values in HTTP headers. Often they will employ an established protocol such as OAuth for wide compatibility and compliance. I don't know Wordpress specifically but I wonder if it has such features, or plugins which can do it.

Comment: @ADyson sure, this is just intended to be used by my own web client and a way to store the tokens safely on the server instead of storing them in the client.

Comment: Cookies are always stored in the client-side too - the whole point of a cookie is that the browser keeps a copy of it

Comment: @ADyson let me rephrase then, purpose is to store safe cookies so that they are inaccessible by the client.

Comment: `I'm assuming some type of headers needs to be passed for the server to recognize that it's the same user that set the cookie`...well normally a browser Session (which is also implemented using cookies in the background) will allow you to identify a user. It's a bit unclear what _exactly_ you're trying to do with your cookies, or why.

Comment: `purpose is to store safe cookies so that they are inaccessible by the client`...this is an oxymoron. If you set a cookie, it will be transmitted to the browser. That's the whole point of cookies. I wonder if you're barking up the wrong tree and need a different solution to your requirement entirely. If you could clarify the overall purpose it might help us to set you on the right track.

Comment: @ADyson I will try to clarify. I am trying to use HTTP ONLY cookies, that can't be accessed by the client, to avoid things like XSS attacks for authenticated users on the web client. The backend of the client is the REST API.

Comment: None of that appears to make any sense. Cookies are designed to be sent to the browser. Forget about cookies for a moment and answer the broader question about what you are trying to achieve. Is your intention simply to store data on the server which cannot be accessed from the client-side, but which is specific to an individual user? If so, you could use something like the Session for that (for temporary storage), or a database or file (for long-term storage). Mitigating XSS attacks is, of course, a much bigger topic overall.

Comment: P.S. I understand that a HTTP-only cookie helps to prevent XSS. What I don't understand is why you would want to set one in this scenario, specifically. What advantage do you get from that, compared to just storing data in the Session or whatever?

Comment: Why is everybody about to reinvent the wheel today? Wordpress comes with a ready built REST API and the cookie auth can easily be extended by plugins to support oAuth or JWT... https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/

Comment: @ADyson Yes sure, it can be stored in Session, and that is basically what I am trying to achieve, but with a secure session cookie if that makes sense. Problem is that the server doesn't recognize additional requests, so effectively the user is always logged out.

Comment: `but with a secure session cookie if that makes sense`...session cookies are already basically secure. None of the Session data ever leaves the server. Only a Session cookie, which simply contains a unique identifier, is ever stored in the browser. And this cookie will be automatically transmitted between browser and server during every request, without you needing to do any extra code. You can use the Session to store things like the user's authenticated status, etc.

Comment: You should probably do some background reading about sessions, security, cookies. Here's some that look relevant to your particular question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36877/how-do-you-set-up-use-httponly-cookies-in-php, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68091086/http-only-cookies-vs-session

Comment: And yes volkerschulz is right, as I suspected earlier, Wordpress probably already has all the functionality you need anyway, without you needing to worry about it, or risk creating something which isn't entirely secure.

Comment: Of course Wordpress has authentication features, but I'm trying to create something that suits my own needs. Here is an article on the default auth which is not good for my needs https://remonpel.nl/2018/06/wordpress-rest-api-nonce-sense/ m and regarding using JWT; I want a safe place to store the tokens.

Comment: Is that still true? The article is 5 years old. Maybe it got fixed (hopefully)?

Comment: @ADyson It is still very true, and of course I've tried different authentication methods for Wordpress. Right now I want to create something simple that works for me. Goal is to create JWT tokens so that auth can be done by different clients, but have a specific endpoint for my web client to store the token on the server rather than returning it in the response and store it unsafely in localstorage or a cookie.

Comment: An auth token would be reasonably safe in a http-only cookie. Or you could just not use token-based auth at all for browser clients and rely on traditional authenticated sessions

Comment: Yes, Wordpress still uses nonces, and so should you. If you (for some reason) do not want to, you can also use WP's REST API without them and provide your very own login and authentication function right when setting up the routes.

Comment: @volkerschulz hence the questions

Comment: @ADyson yes it would be reasonably safe in a http-only cookie, that's why I'm trying to get it to work but am unable to.

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer: Using cookie auth without nonce is open to CSRF attacks and is not recommended!**

To use standard session cookies with the API you simply need to `start_session()`, validate the user and save their `user_id` in `$_SESSION` to make them the current user with each additional request.

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route('custom/v1', '/login/', [
        'methods' => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'customLogin',
        'permission_callback' => '__return_true',
    ]);
});

add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route('custom/v1', '/check-cookie/', [
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'checkCookie',
        'permission_callback' => 'userOk',
    ]);
});

// Hooked to /login endpoint
function customLogin(\WP_REST_Request $request) {
    session_start();

    $user = wp_signon([
        'user_login' =>  $request->get_param('user_login'), 
        'user_password' =>  $request->get_param('user_password')
    ]);

    if(isset($user->ID)) {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user->ID;
        return true;
    } elseif(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
        unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
    }

    return $user;
}

// Hooked to /check-cookie endpoint
function checkCookie() {
    $data = [
        "message" => "YOU ARE IN!"
    ];

    return $data;
}

// Callback to check whether user is allowed to do certain things
function userOk() {
    session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
        return false;
    }

    $user = get_user_by('id', $_SESSION['user_id']); 
    if(isset($user->ID)) {
        wp_set_current_user($user->ID, $user->user_login);
    }
    
    return current_user_can('edit_posts');
}
```

This should get you started. If you don't want to interfere with the regular session cookie (and / or want to set HTTP only), add appropriate options to `session_start()`. Once again: I do not recommend to do it this way!